# Functions throws error on recursing large numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and have this function:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0) * n + f(n - 1) 
f(999)
```

It works until f(993), but not f(999). When I try, infinite amount of errors keep popping out. I don't get it. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

**Edit:**
  Thanks everyone for your answers. I guess i'm better off using iteration in python.

Comment: Yes, if the last line of output is `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: This can verily easily be changed into a loop to avoid such a problem.

Comment: Having the errors in question would certainly help.

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better off using the iterative:

```
def f(n):
    s = 0
    while n > 0:
        s += (n%3==0 or n%5==0)*n
        n -= 1
    return s
print f(999)
```

which outputs:

```
233168
```

Also one could write this with `sum`:

```
def f(n):
    return sum((n%3==0 or n%5==0)*n for n in reversed(range(1,n+1)))
```

Comment: `(n%3==0 or n%5==0)*n` could also be written `n if n%3==0 or n%5==0 else 0`, which might be more clear. Or you could reverse the logic and do `0 if n%3 or n%5 else n`. Or in your last version, since you're using a generator expression, you could put the condition at the end, rather than as part of the expression: `sum(n for n in range(1, n+1) if n%3==0 or n%5==0)`

Answer (score 4):

In Python, recursion is limited to **999** recursion call.

If you really want to change the limit of recursion call, you can use [sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit).

For example:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

However, changing recursion limit can be **dangerous**. The stack frames might get too big.

[From the doc:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)

> This limit prevents **infinite** recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python. It can be set by `setrecursionlimit()`.

**What you can do is:**

Like @Dan D. said, you better rewriting your code iteratively. [Here is the reason why you should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651200/1031955).

Answer (score 3):

As you have already known from the other answers as to the reason for your code failure, and you have possibly got alternative solutions either by increasing the recursion limit or using an iterative solution

Alternatively, there is a smarter approach to your problem which requires a bit introspection to what you actually want to achieve

> Sum all factors of 3 and 5 from 0 to N

Which simply boils down to

```
>>> def fn_ab(n):
    numbers = [0]*n
    numbers[0:n:3] = range(0,n,3)
    numbers[0:n:5] = range(0,n,5)
    return sum(numbers)
```

Comment: Or better, `sum(n for n in range(1, n+1) if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0)`