# Benefits to recursive function over using loops outside of readability?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, loops, recursion

I just read about recursive functions and how it uses computer memory.  Seems like there is no performance benefit to using recursive functions given that it creates a copy of variables in each iteration.  In loops, seems like we just overwrite the variables in each iteration.

Is there any benefit to recursive functions OUTSIDE of making your code easier to read?  I am particularly interested in knowing if recursive functions will provide any benefit to computing performance (will my code run either faster or take up less memory).

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651112/is-recursion-ever-faster-than-looping?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is recursion ever faster than looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651112/is-recursion-ever-faster-than-looping)

Comment: Good luck writing a parser without recursion. Certain types of problems are very hard to tackle without using recursion as a tool.