# Why iteration is so much more time-consuming than recursion?

Tags: recursion, iteration

Today when I am solving Fibonacci arrays, I meet with a very strange thing. Recursion only takes 16ms, but iteration takes 80ms. I have tried to optimize my iteration (such as I use a vector container to fulfill my stack) but iteration is still much slower than recursion. It doesn't make sense because recursion still builds a stack at OS level, which is more time-consuming than iteration.
Here is my iteration code:

```
class Solution {
    public:
        int fib(int n) {
            std::stack<int, std::vector<int>> st;
            st.push(n);
            int result = 0;
            int temp = 0;
            while(!st.empty()) {
                temp = st.top(); st.pop();
                if(temp == 1) result++;
                else if(temp == 0) continue;
                else {
                    st.push(temp - 1);
                    st.push(temp - 2);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

Here is my recursion code

```
class Solution {
    public:
        int fib(int n) {
            if(n == 0) return 0;
            if(n == 1) return 1;
            else return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
    };
```

Well, I have searched for the reason. According to [Is recursion ever faster than looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651112/is-recursion-ever-faster-than-looping?rq=1), recursion is more time-consuming than iteration in an imperative language. But C++ is one of the imperative languages, it is not convincing.

***I think I find the reason. You can help me check if there is any incorrect in my analysis?***

The reason why recursion is faster than iteration is that if you use an STL container as a stack, it would be allocated in heap space.

When the PC pointer wants to access the stack, cache missing might happen, which is greatly expensive as for a small scale problem.

However, as for the Fibonacci solution, the code length is not very long. So the PC pointer can easily jump to the function's beginning. If you use a static int array, the result is satisfying.

Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int fib(int n) {        
        int arr[1000];
        arr[0] = n;
        int s = 1;
        int result = 0;
        int temp;
        while (s) {
            temp = arr[s-1];
            s--;
            switch (temp) {
            case 1:
                result++;
                break;
            case 0:
                continue;
                break;
            default:
                arr[s++] = temp - 1;
                arr[s++] = temp - 2;
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }       
};
```

Comment: One advantage that the thread's stack has is that it's all allocated up-front for you. Perhaps what you're seeing here is the cost of resizing your stack as you add elements to it. Perhaps try preallocating enough space up-front. (You only need 47 IIRC, since `fib(48)` would overflow `int`)

Comment: Sorry. I have tried it but it still falls behind the recursion even if I preallocate enough space.