# I have a function that changes months into numbers, but I'd like to add 0 before the month's number

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a date like:

```
19/août/2016 (août = august)
```

And I have the following function which changes the month into a number:

```
function swapMonthForNumber(str:String):String {
    //do the same line of code for every item in the array
    for(var i:int=0;i<months.length;i++){
        //i is the item, which is 0 based, so we have to add 1 to make the right month number
        str = str.replace(months[i],String(+i+1));
    }

    //return the updated string
    return str;
}

str = swapMonthForNumber(mySharedObject.data.theDate);
trace("Php will use this date :"+str);
```

So `str` will be `19/8/2016`, but I want `str` to be `19/08/2016` (adding a `0` before the `8`).

How can I do this?

Comment: What does `String(+i+1)` do? I've never seen that before.

Comment: You're probably going to want to check if the month is less than 10, and if so prepend a `"0"` to `String(i+1)` by doing `"0" + String(i+1)` (not sure if `+` is the concatenate operator in AS3, but I think it is).

Comment: @JonnyHenly in (+i+1) the leading + is redundant since it doesn't change the sign of i.

Comment: @dene : String(+i+1) was not edited but used by user5870211 in the original message I think. But for sure it's redundant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the reference of the [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class!

If forgot to mention this link : [flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter(requestedLocaleIDName:String, dateStyle:String = "long", timeStyle:String = "long")
```

Here is an example.

```
import flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter;
var df:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT, DateTimeStyle.SHORT, DateTimeStyle.NONE);
var currentDate:Date = new Date(2016,7,19);
var shortDate:String = df.format(currentDate);
trace (shortDate);

// output : 19/08/2016
```

[DateTimeStyle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeStyle.html)

[LocaleID](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/LocaleID.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding leading zeros to a number is commonly called *zero padding.*

Below is a function to do this, from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666531/what-would-you-use-to-zero-pad-a-number-in-flex-as3).

> ```
> public function zeroPad(number:int, width:int):String {
>    var ret:String = ""+number;
>    while( ret.length < width )
>        ret="0" + ret;
>    return ret;
> }
> ```

In your `swapMonthForNumber` function, in the for loop, swap the code for this:

```
var month = zeroPad(i + 1, 2);
str = str.replace(months[i], month);
```

Comment: @ dene : I don't know why you suggest to use a self made method since you may easily use the built in DateTimeFormatter Class?

Comment: I'm not sure about the gain of time between the two methods...

a getTimer() after a lot of conversions could probably show what is the best way to convert / format the Date Object in this case.