# Leading Zero on Single Digits (Flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using Flash CS3 - AS 3.0.

I have the following code that I am using to make the image count external: I am not sure if you all are familiar with Slideshow pro (I dont think that you need to in order to help me).

```
function albumStuff(event:SSPDataEvent) {
     if (event.type=="albumData") {
     total1.text =  event.data.totalImages;
     }
}
```

How would I make a leading zero come up infront of the number that comes up in that text field as long as it's 9 and under?

I hope my question isn't confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 function leadingZero(num : Number) : String {
    if(num < 10) {
       return "0" + num;
    }
    return num.toString();
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but how would I incorporate this into the code i currently have :/ i just started doing 3.0 , cause i had to do it for this client

Comment: total1.text =  leadingZero(Number(event.data.totalImages));

Comment: I greatly dislike this answer. What if num was -10? That is "less than 10" and would get a zero appended...

Answer (score 4):

To further optimize Seanonymous' answer:

```
function addLeadingZero(val:Number, places:uint):String
{
    var result:String = val.toString();
    for(var i:int = result.length; i < places; i++)
    {
        result = '0' + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Speed will only noticeable when iterating hundreds of strings/numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better method that will work if you have more than one decimal place (so something like 0001 to 0991 etc.)

Step 1: create a placeholder variable that has the max number of 0's

> var leadingZeroes:String="000000000";

Step 2: turn your number into a string

> var intToString:String=String(myInteger);

Step 3: shave off the end of your placeholder based on the number of characters in your number

> leadingZeroes=leadingZeroes.substr(0,leadingZeroes.length-intToString.length);

Step 4: print the concatenated string to your textfield (or use it wherever)

> TxtField.text=String(leadingZeroes+intToString);

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Adding one zero to numbers below ten is all well & good, but if you want to be a bit more thorough this will allow you to add any number of zeros:

```
function alz( value:uint, places:Number ):String { //Add Leading Zeros
    var result:String = value.toString();
    while ( result.length < places ) {
        result = '0' + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use the same function for varying numbers of leading zeros:

```
var timeText:String = alz( minutes, 2) + ":" + 
                        alz( seconds, 2 ) + "." + 
                        alz( milliseconds, 4 );
```

timeText: 03:08.0042

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Casalib's NumberUtil](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_util_NumberUtil.html#addLeadingZero).

[The library's website](http://casalib.org/).

For a new comer, the library provides a lot of useful little functions and it is a very good learning material when you look at its source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner way:

```
private function leadingZeros(value:int, numDigits:int):String
{
    return String(new Array(numDigits + 1).join("0") + String(value)).substr(-numDigits, numDigits);
}
```

though, I'm not certain if the Array's join() method is faster than the while loop.

this thread is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611873/ruby-like-question-make-this-function-shorter-actionscript-3/611961#611961)

however, that one's title has "ruby" in it, when we're talking about as3.  i suggesting making that one a duplicate of this.