# Replacing words in a String by letters

Tags: string, actionscript-3, replace, str-replace

I've got this string :

```
var str:String = mySharedObject.data.theDate;
```

where `mySharedObject.data.theDate` can contain the word January, February, March..etc (depends on which button the user clicked).

Is it possible to tell to my code to replace "January" by "1" (if `mySharedObject` contain the word January), "February" by "2"...etc ?

Comment: Is this in any particular language?

Comment: In which language exactly?

Comment: AS3 sorry forgot to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic way to do what you'd like, is to the use the `replace` method of a string.

```
str = str.replace("January","1");
```

Now, you could repeat or chain together for all 12 months (eg `str = str.replace("January","1").replace("February","2").replace("March","3")..etc`) or you could do it in a loop:

```
//have an array of all 12 months in order
var months:Array = ["January","February","March","April","May"]; //etc

//create a function to replace all months with the corresponding number
function swapMonthForNumber(str:String):String {
    //do the same line of code for every item in the array
    for(var i:int=0;i<months.length;i++){
        //i is the item, which is 0 based, so we have to add 1 to make the right month number
        str = str.replace(months[i],String(i+1));
    }
    //return the updated string
    return str;
}

var str:String = swapMonthForNumber(mySharedObject.data.theDate);
```

Now, there are a few other ways to replace strings in ActionScript that are all a little different in terms of complexity and performance, but if you're just getting started I would stick with the `replace` method.

The only possible caveat with `replace` is that it only replaces the first instance of the word, so if your string was `"January January January"`, it would come out as `"1 January January"`.

Comment: Quick question : if I don't want January to be 1 but 01, (add a zero on single digits). How can I do that with the loop `swapMonthForNumber`

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450518/leading-zero-on-single-digits-flash